# C# @ line break functionality equivalent in Java

Tags: java

In C#, you can use verbatim string literals so that you don't have to include '+' sign to concatenate strings on multiple lines. For example:

```
var fooStr = @"This is a foo string.
              It will have a corresponding bar sibling string";
```

In Java, the same code will be written as:

```
String fooStr = "This is a foo string." +
                "It will have a corresponding bar sibling string";
```

I know there is no equivalent of verbatim strings in Java and you have to escape the strings yourself. But is there an equivalent of this specific functionality? Or is there a library which helps achieve this?